# pictures in jframe not loading after compiled

Tags: java, image, swing, netbeans, jframe

so this is how my code looks in NetBeans:
    [image]

and this is how it looks after I complied it

[image]

I think it has to do with this

```
ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Graphics/BackgroundConcept.jpg"));

img = background.getImage();
```

I put all the picture in the `src` folder and it wont load BUT it load other picture for the title screen.

But I'm using this type of input

```
Image image=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Graphics/titleScreen.jpg")).getImage();  
               g.drawImage(image,0,0,this);
```

and

```
Image GameCredits=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Graphics/credits.gif")).getImage();
```

The problem is I'm not adding it to a JFrame.
It is long code so I'll post it in pastebucket, basically its moving the background images as I move.

It works in NetBeans but I needed a compiled version.

http://www.pastebucket.com/14192

Comment: Hopefully this answer will be of some help on the topic, regarding how to [Add Images to your Project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/1057230)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.com/)

Comment: This is a very common topic around here... Searching this site will get you the fastest help.